# How to get Magick::ImageList?

Tags: ruby, imagemagick, flickr, rmagick

I am a novice in *Ruby*, and I don't know how to do it

My aim is to make a photo collage , there are several steps to do it:

1. connect to *flickr* service via gem [flickraw](http://rubygems.org/gems/flickraw) - done
2. ask `flickr` for specific photos - `flickr.photos.search(:tags=>ARGV)` - done
3. get `ImageList` from p.2 - ???
4. process images to make a collage - ???

I would like to note, that I can get url of every image from flickr response...

Answer (score 0):

When you have the urls of the images you can use `Net::HTTP` to read the images. 
See also [How do I download a file over HTTP using Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877190/how-do-i-download-a-file-over-http-using-ruby) or [Download a zip file through Net::HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386159/download-a-zip-file-through-nethttp)

After that you can try the solution of [Creating a collage from a collection of images in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7629167/creating-a-collage-from-a-collection-of-images-in-ruby)